# The usage of "so" in these sentences

Tags: word-usage, so

I heard in the movie *Kubo and the Two Strings*:

> I do **so** love the festival.
>
> We just need your other eye. Your grandfather admires it **so**.

It appears to function as an adverb, possibly meaning *very much*. Does it have the same meaning as:

> We are **so** going to fail the exam.

If so, I would understand the first sentence, but the second sentence where **so** appears at the end still sounds strange. What is this usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possible answer here in [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355776/can-you-end-a-sentence-with-so-in-this-way).
 Also there is a page in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_(sentence_closer)) saying:

> So is a word that may be used to end sentences. When ending a sentence, it may be:
>
> - a coordinating conjunctive to refer backwards to something previously mentioned
> - a coordinating conjunctive dangling "so" (sometimes called trailing "so")[1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355776/can-you-end-a-sentence-with-so-in-this-way) to refer forwards to something that may be said
> - an intensifying adverb.

Comment: You shouldn’t just link to an answer elsewhere - you should include the relevant information and explain how it answers the question.